# Laravel Mime Check runs out of memory

Tags: php, laravel, validation, mime

This question has been asked in a similar manner before, but I think this is different enough to warrant a new question.

On docker or Ubuntu based systems, laravel's default mime validation rule works without issues:

```
'file' => 'required|mimes:bmp,docx,jpg,png|max:3200',
```

On CentOS, this same rule with the same php.ini settings needs 184MB+ to check the mime type of the same file.

Any thoughts and suggestions are welcomed

Comment: No ideas offhand, but you might run the xdebug profiler on both machines and then compare the results. It should show you where the bottleneck is occurring in the framework code and might give you something useful to search for

Comment: Finally found out that this was due to a bug in the way we were using Laravel's S3 driver, which caused it to use the "contents" check instead the native unix mimetype check.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found out that this was due to the way we were using Laravel's S3 driver, which caused it to use the "contents" check instead the native unix mimetype check

#Instead of

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put('filename','contents as a string');
```

#We are now using

```
Storage::disk('s3')->putFileAs('/', $fileHandle, 'filename')
```